# iOS: Show PDF in WebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, uiwebview

I´m trying to show a pdf in a webview, but the webview is always white / blank.
if i log the path from the local file, it can be logged, so the file is there..

Here is my code:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fileName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

(webView is an iboutlet)

Maik

Comment: are you sure that you've connected everything up on IB? Your code seems right... are you sure that the white/blank view you're seeing is the webview?

Comment: Yes, i cann scroll it, and zoom etc...

Comment: just because you can scroll and zoom doesn't mean its "connected" ... in a debugger, is webView == nil?

Comment: nope... I created a new project, copied all sources, and it worked... i don´t know why...

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the User Interaction Enabled & Multiple Touch are enabled. 
[image: check for the following properties]

Answer (score 0):

Your targetURL is maybe nil, please debug this.

If the targetUrl is nil, this is  maybe the 'path' has space.

So you should encode the path:

```
//Encode Url
+(NSString *) urlEncodeString:(NSString *) str
{
    return [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the whole characters rather than not just the space is more appropriate.Try this one for encoding the path of a file.

```
-(NSString *)urlenc:(NSString *)val{
    CFStringRef safeString =
    CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                            (CFStringRef)val,
                                            NULL,
                                            CFSTR("/%&=?$#+-~@<>|*,.()[]{}^!şığüöçĞÜŞİÖÇ"),
                                            kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", safeString];
}
```